# Get 404 error for sub links from wordpress for second website

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Managed WordPress Hosting, and I can only have one Website on it, and WordPress is preinstalled, now I installed a PHP script website beside the WordPress website in a subfolder in the root, and I import the Database to WordPress database, The PHP website's homepage with this link Example.com/1/ will load without any problem, but I get 404 error from WordPress website for sub links : example.com/1/sublinks

What should I do? The website beside WordPress will run in localhost without any problem

Comment: Do you update your **wp-config.php**, and **.htaccess** files as recommended by WordPress? If you did, please post your code (remove your DB username, password before post).

Comment: @vee As i mentioned the wordpress website is pre installed and the wordpress run without any problem , the problem is the script that i installed besides the wordpress , i change the config file of script , so that the main page of the script will run, the problem is the additional layers, after slash , abc.com/script/problem

Comment: and i didn't change the .htaccess

Comment: However it is still possible that problem come from mod rewrite in **.htaccess** file.

Answer (score 0):

First, delete the .htaccess file, and after that update permalinks by the admin panel. please follow the below steps.
wp-admin > settings > permalinks